# Read real time multiple sensor

Tags: sensors

In case you have multiple sensors (temperature, pressure, etc) up to 20 in a system with different electrical interfaces. What is the best way to read values simultaneously (at exact the same time point). Can somebody provide some starting points, guidelines, to tackle this problem.

I like to use microcontroller preferred STM32 or alternative Arduino platform.

Thanks.
J.

Comment: you would need a separate microcontroller for each of the sensors ... all the microcontrollers would have to be synchronized so that each microcontroller reads its associated sensor at exactly the same time

Comment: In reality, reading them all, one after an other, is highly unlikely to give misleading results and is certainly the simplest solution. Otherwise, you have to send a command to each of the 20 MCUs at ***exactly*** the same time, or find some way to synch their Real Time Clocks to th e microsecond. Do't overthink this; just read them one at a time.